# How to share Facebook page using Xamarin.iOS Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin

I use this code in my apps to share Facebook pages:

```
class func shareWithDialog(viewController : UIViewController, delegate : FBSDKSharingDelegate, contentTitle: String, contentUrl: NSURL = url, contentDescription: String) {
    let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentTitle = contentTitle
    content.contentURL = contentUrl
    content.contentDescription = contentDescription

    let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
    dialog.fromViewController = viewController
    dialog.shareContent = content
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.FeedBrowser
    dialog.delegate = delegate
    dialog.show()
}
```

In the native code (above) `FBSDKShareLinkContent.contentURL` is set to the facebook page I want to share. I'm using [Xamarin.Facebook.iOS.4.5.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Facebook.iOS/4.5.1) nuget package to add this functionality into a Xamarin app. The thing is that this SDK is similar to the native SDK but class `ShareLinkContent` doesn't have the property `contentURL` (it does have a `ImageURL` property).

I might be using the wrong class, but I could'n find the right class (other classes in the SDK are intended for sharing images and videos).

Comment: Hi @agarwaen, I have stumbled on to this problem as well. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @JasonSteele No luck so far. I have my app waiting for this feature. For some reason `FBSDKShareLinkContent` is not identical to the native version. If you find some workaround please share it.

Comment: I found that it has a method `SetContentUrl` - have you seen that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Jason Steele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600548/jason-steele) I looked closer and see that `contentUrl` property was replaced by `setContentURL()` method. I used this method to point to the Facebook page I wanted to share and it worked. 
It was a silly question after all ;)